# commons-configuration custom configuration file

Tags: java, configuration-files, apache-commons

I'd to save configuration as a list of sth like:
152.158.1545.415:80 Ok
152.108.145.415:80 
152.158.115.415:80 500

instead of:

proxy= 152.108.145.415:80
proxy= 152.108.145.415:80 
...
and read it. ( 152.108.145.415 as a string 80  as a number ). 
Can I do such a customisation in this library (commons-configuration)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `PropertiesConfiguration` you can customize the layout for the "proxy" property and have the values on a single line like this:

```
proxy=152.158.115.415:80,152.158.115.415:80,152.158.115.415:80
```

You do this by calling:

```
configuration.getLayout().setSingleLine("proxy", true);
```